# Java 3-SUM code behaves unexpectedly

Tags: java, file, oop

I've had a go at solving the 3-sum problem where you read the number of elements of the array and then the array itself from a file and then post the triplets to another file.

For those of you who don't know the 3-sum problem, here it is: 3SUM problem asks if a given set of n real numbers contains three elements that sum to zero. If so, return the triplets. The triplets must be distinct.

So here's my code:

```
   import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main 
    { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception            
        { int number_elements=0;
        int[] array_elements=null;
        File file = new File("date.in.txt");     
        File file2 = new File("date.out.txt");

        try  
            {Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            number_elements=input.nextInt();
            array_elements = new int[number_elements];
            int contor=0;
            while(input.hasNext())
                { array_elements[contor]=input.nextInt();
                contor++; }}

        catch(IOException e)
            { System.out.println("eroare"); }


        Arrays.sort(array_elements);


        try 
            { PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file2); 
            output.print("The triplets who sum to 0: ");
            for(int i=0;i<number_elements-2;i++)
                { int j=i+1;
                int k=number_elements-1;
                while(k>=j)
                    { int temp=array_elements[i]+array_elements[j]+array_elements[k];
                    if(temp==0)
                        { output.println("( "+array_elements[i]+", "+array_elements[j]+", "+array_elements[k]+" )\n");
                        break; }
                    else if(temp>0)
                        k--;
                    else if(temp<0)
                        j++; }}
           output.close(); }

        catch(IOException e)
            { System.out.println("eroare"); }
        }}
```

And for the input:

> 8
>
> 3 1 2 -5 -2 10 7 3

I get

> The triplets who sum to 0: ( -5, -2, 7 )
>
> ( -2, 1, 1 )

And I don't really understand why, I mean,

> ( -2, 1, 1 )

Don't even belong to my array. If someone could point out my mistake, I'd be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(-2,1,1) does not belong to your array. However, -2 and 1 does. So you can conclude that the "1" is being repeated. To fix this, you should change the condition of the while loop to `k > j` instead of `k >= j`.